# Copy and paste using vi duplicates comment lines

Tags: linux, vi

On a windows PC, I copy the following to the tooltip.

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header 
   // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   // Content Type: text/plain
   response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});

   // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   response.end('Hello World\n');
}).listen(8081);

// Console will print the message
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
```

Using puTTY, I then open vi on a linux box, press "i" for insert, and rightclick the mouse as I always do.  But this time, I get:

```
var http = require("http");

http.createServer(function (request, response) {

   // Send the HTTP header
   //    // HTTP Status: 200 : OK
   //       // Content Type: text/plain
   //          response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'text/plain'});
   //
   //                // Send the response body as "Hello World"
   //                   response.end('Hello World\n');
   //                   }).listen(8081);
   //
   //                   // Console will print the message
   //                   console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8081/');
   //
```

As see, vi automatically inserts extra `//`.  What causes this and how do I prevent it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`:set paste` before paste. It disables auto indent and auto completion temporarily. And you can revert settings with `:set nopaste`

Comment: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Toggle_auto-indenting_for_code_paste